# Send telegram message directly to phone number with c#

Tags: c#, message, telegram, phone-number

i want to send a telegram message directly to a phone number that is not in my contacts.
with TLSharp its possible to send a message to a contact but its not possible to send message to a phone number.
is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Create a contact with the unknown number. Send the message and delete the contact. :D

Comment: The core API supports Non-Contact recepiants: https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.sendMessage https://core.telegram.org/type/InputPeer https://core.telegram.org/constructor/userForeign Does TLSharp support that InputPeer Type?

Comment: How should create a contact? i didnt find a method in TLSharp or in Telegram APIs for creating a contact.

Answer (score 0):

How should create a contact? i didnt find a method in TLSharp or in Telegram APIs for creating a contact.

Comment: Please add a comment rather than a new answer

Answer (score 0):

You can first create the contact (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40850765/3769451)) and then send a message to it. If you need more info please comment and I will try to answer.

Comment: Please add a comment rather than a new answer